# How to have an image overlap the edge of a div

Tags: html, css, overlap

I've got a picture of what I need to make this box look like, shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IODrN.png

However I haven't done anything to do with overlapping before and haven't been able to find much help on how to approach this problem. Here's the code I've got so far, if someone could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <div id="TennantAnn">

    <div id="AnnIcon">

    <img src="Images/AnnouncementIcon.PNG"> 

    </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
   #TennantAnn {
   display:inline-block;
   width:450px;
   height:620px;
   margin-bottom:60px;
   box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px 5px #F0F0F0;
   margin-top:30px;
   margin-left:120px;
   border-color:#F0F0F0;
   overflow:visible;
   } 

   #AnnIcon {
   margin-right:1000px;
   }
```

I gave AnnIcon the margin-right:1000px; just to test whether or not it'd move over at all, but it doesn't, and I don't know how to make it so that it will get to the position I want it to be in.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [absolute positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/), this takes the element in question and pulls it completely out of normal flow. You then use `top,left,right,bottom` to position the element absolutely from the first non statically positioned parent element. (ie, "stick this child x distance from the side/corner of its parent")

```
   #TennantAnn {
   display:inline-block;
   width:450px;
   height:620px;
   margin-bottom:60px;
   box-shadow: -5px -5px 5px 5px #F0F0F0;
   margin-top:30px;
   margin-left:120px;
   border-color:#F0F0F0;
   overflow:visible;
   position:relative; /* parent must not be statically positioned */
   } 

   #AnnIcon {
   position:absolute;
   top:-15px;
   left:-15px;
   }
```

Comment: Taking Dylan's ideas and running with them, [here is a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/qns10fpc/)

Answer (score 1):

Do `position: relative` and then `left: 1em` or `top: 1em` or whichever direction you want to move it in. This will move the element *relative to it's original position* but outside the normal document flow.

Comment: I think `absolute` makes more sense in this case, as I doubt they want the original position of the icon to be reserved.